# How can I prevent apache kafka from logging to stdout

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, log4j

I have an apache kafka cluster, with kafka version kafka_2.12-2.0.1 and I'm triing to prevent it from logging to the console, I want it to log only to files, but with no success and now it drives me crazy. My log4j version is log4j-1.2.17 and unfortunately I can not upgrade due to my company's strict rules. My log4j.properties currently looks like the following:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Unspecified loggers and loggers with additivity=true output to server.log and stdout
# Note that INFO only applies to unspecified loggers, the log level of the child logger is used otherwise
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, kafkaAppender

#log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.cleanerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/log-cleaner.log
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.authorizerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-authorizer.log
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

# Change the two lines below to adjust ZK client logging
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO

# Change the two lines below to adjust the general broker logging level (output to server.log and stdout)
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO

# Change to DEBUG or TRACE to enable request logging
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false

# Uncomment the lines below and change log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$ to TRACE for additional output
# related to the handling of requests
#log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=false
log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false

log4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=DEBUG, cleanerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=false

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=TRACE, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false

# Access denials are logged at INFO level, change to DEBUG to also log allowed accesses
log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=INFO, authorizerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.authorizer.logger=false
```

What should I do to solve this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Don't you get server.log?

Comment: @PrashantPandey yep, I get server.log from the kafkaAppender. And I store them in a separate file so I don't want the server log to be logged to the console also (/var/log/messages). Or isn't that what you have been asked?

Comment: Kafka doesn't write to `/var/log/messages` out of the box, so something else is doing that, and the company should be stricter about **not** using log4j in favor of slf4j (which is what Kafka actually uses)

Comment: @cricket_007 actually if I hit `ps -ef | grep kafka` I can see _/apache-kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar_ in the output. It means that the kafka uses the slf4j? _/apache-kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar_ is also there. I'm getting confused.

Comment: @cricket_007 aren't log4j and slf4j two different things? One is a facade and one is its implementation?

Comment: @weces it uses a logging bridge, yes, but it can be overwritten to use logback for example

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, I think I kind of understand it now. Do you know an example of how should I use logback with kafka? Should I change the pom.xml of slf4j, build it and replace the jar etc.? To be honest, I would prefer logback also, I use it with Cassandra and other apps also and is much more configurable and faster, as I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out the problem here, and @cricket_007 was right with his first answer.
So, not long ago rsyslog anf ArcSight got involved to monitor the logs, and I did not think that it may cause the problem. Rsyslog is the one which sends the logs to `/var/log/messages` because of it's wrong config, and it filled `/var/log` so I run out of space. Thats what I wanted to solve with the log4j configuration, but of course I could not, because even if log4j was configured the right way (to not send the log to stdout), rsyslog sent the message there any way and I did not recognized that, I thought log4j is the problematic one.
So thank you all, who tried to help, it is now solved!
Btw, the log4j config now looks like the following:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Unspecified loggers and loggers with additivity=true output to server.log and stdout
# Note that INFO only applies to unspecified loggers, the log level of the child logger is used otherwise
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, kafkaAppender

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=OFF
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.cleanerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/log-cleaner.log
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.authorizerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-authorizer.log
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

# Change the two lines below to adjust ZK client logging
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO

# Change the two lines below to adjust the general broker logging level (output to server.log and stdout)
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO

# Change to DEBUG or TRACE to enable request logging
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false

# Uncomment the lines below and change log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$ to TRACE for additional output
# related to the handling of requests
#log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=false
log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false

log4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=DEBUG, cleanerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=false

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=TRACE, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false

# Access denials are logged at INFO level, change to DEBUG to also log allowed accesses
log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=DEBUG, authorizerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.authorizer.logger=false
```